# Cannot reproduce nvidia-docker2 installation from the tutorial

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, docker, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've been trying to get OpenGL work with nvidia-docker2 to run gazebo in Docker.
I've started to repeat the steps outlined in "1.2 nvidia-docker2" section of this http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration#nvidia-docker2 tutorial.

First, I've found some mistakes in it:

- One should do `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata`, the current installation command does not work -- the installation process hangs when selecting location area
- Package `lsb_release` should be `lsb-release`
- One needs to also install `gnupg` before running `apt-key`

After fixing these I got my Docker image built. But the last step, which should display RViz, tells me

```
root@2e605489cabd:/# rosrun rviz rviz
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

The host system is Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295552/cannot-reproduce-nvidia-docker2-installation-from-the-tutorial/) by [Ilya Kuzovkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/36143/ilya-kuzovkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the answer. On my system I was running docker from under root (`sudo docker` instead of just `docker` inside `run_my_image.sh`).
To allow root user the access to running X server one must run (on the host machine) the following command
`$ xhost +si:localuser:root`
Now I am able to run RViz and Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Ilya Kuzovkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/36143/ilya-kuzovkin/) with karma: 56 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the latest ROS LTS melodic based off from Ubuntu Bionic, `ros:melodic-ros-base-bionic` comes with `libglvnd0` pre installed, so all that is needed is to set the missing Nvidia environmental variables:

```
FROM ros:melodic-ros-base-bionic

# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
    ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics
```

As can be shown here for bionic, although not so yet for stretch:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:melodic-ros-base-bionic dpkg -l libglvnd0
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version          Architecture     Description
+++-=======================-================-================-===========================
ii  libglvnd0:amd64         1.0.0-2ubuntu2   amd64            Vendor neutral GL dispatch library
```

I've updated the wiki, however this should eventually work its way as well into the desktop images with this PR:
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/pull/165

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2018-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1